# GMaps: Crazy values for computeDistanceBetween in android?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm using `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween()` to compute the distance between relatively close points (10-30 meters). This works perfectly in Linux (Chrome and Firefox), but sometimes gives me crazy results in Android. One case that I got was with this:

```
var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.960584,-43.206687999999986);
var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.960584,-43.206939000000034);
alert(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1,p2));
```

It should give 25 meters or so, yet once I got hundred of thousands of meters. Again, it is not always that I get crazy values, just "sometimes", probably related with lots of computations?

Is this a well known bug? If it is, I cannot use this method and would have to make my own.

Thanks,

L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is an Android bug. I think this could very well explain why in the **MyTracks** app I usually get randomly points in other continents and huge distances.
I computed the distance function with the method below, and now I always get the correct values. In particular, if this is what it looks, this is a very serious bug for Android app that uses this function.

In case anyone cares, this is the distance function between to `LatLng` p and q:

```
function dist(p,q) {
  var c = Math.PI/180;
  // Google (gives randomly wrong results in Android!)
  //return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p,q);
  // Chord
  //return 9019995.5222 * Math.sqrt((1-Math.cos(c*(p.lat()-q.lat()))) 
  //   + (1-Math.cos(c*(p.lng()-q.lng()))) * Math.cos(c*p.lat()) * Math.cos(c*q.lat()));
  // Taylor for chord
  return 111318.845 * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p.lat()-q.lat(),2)
       + Math.pow(p.lng()-q.lng(),2) * Math.cos(c*p.lat()) * Math.cos(c*q.lat()));
}
```

Notice that these are the computations for the chord, that is, the distance in R^3, not the geodesic distance in the sphere. Certainly more than enough for hiking/car travel computations using GPS. I ended up using the Taylor expansion since it is precise to 1/10 mm, and less tough with the CPU.

Comment: It looks like Google changed the function in the latest API: `return 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin((c - e) / 2), 2) + Math.cos(c) * Math.cos(e) * Math.pow(Math.sin((d - f) / 2), 2)))`